# Insert row into data imported using IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I have two sheets:

SheetA contains dates. It is the reference data.

SheetB contains dates and data on events that occurred on those dates. This sheet is updated regularly.

I am using IMPORTRANGE in SheetB to pull data from SheetA.

I sometimes need to insert rows into SheetB. For example, sometimes two events occur on the same date and I need a row for each.

However, when I insert a new row into the imported data in SheetB the new row is automatically filled with IMPORTRANGE data from SheetA.

I think there may be a solution with ADDRESS but I can't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As long as IMPORTRANGE returns a single array of multiple rows you are not going to be able to split those apart at all easily. Your best bet may be to convert the array into a standard range (Ctrl+C/Ctrl+Shift+V) and start the process all over if the source changes.

You might be able to combine two ranges (one from each sheet) in a QUERY that you sort by date.

Comment: Thanks @pnuts. I feared that might be the answer :)